# How to set daily Update limit on Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm new to Django. I have created one Django App where users can update their Shift Timing(Morning/Evening/General) and based on this Shift Timing I am taking real-time data from Django Model and running Linux script which will be evaluating user shift timing with allowed timing to use the application.

I have used Django import and export which allows the user to upload multiple users' data by using a **.xls** file from the front-end. Now here I want to apply some limit for example suppose my model is having **5000** records so I want that only ***50%*** of its records should be allowed to modify whether it is added through .xls file or by clicking on update single records(I am doing this because I don't want to allow updaton of more than 50% object in single day). Is there any easiest way to implement this requirement?

I have checked https://pypi.org/project/django-limits/ (django-limits 0.0.6)but did not understood from step 3.

I am adding my **models.py**

```
class CTA(models.Model):
    AConnectID = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    Shift_timing = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=SHIFT_CHOICES, default='9.00-6.00')
    EmailID = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True, )
    Vendor_Company = models.CharField(max_length=64, )
    Project_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    SerialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=19, default="")
    Reason = models.TextField(max_length=180)
    last_updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('/ctall')
```

Is there any way through which I can set the max record updation limit in the ***models.py*** level?

Any help OR suggestion on this would be highly appreciated.
**Note:** Here I want field to update based on primary key(here I am considering **id**)
example: suppose if I am having model **A** and it contain 500 records and with the help of .xls file I want to change 200 records(here these 200 records will change based on id/existing in 500).

Adding **view** code for file upload:

```
def upload_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.user.username)
        # logger.info(messages, extra={'username': request.user.username})
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="CTA_ShiftTiming.xls"'
        wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
        ws = wb.add_sheet('CTA_ShiftChange Data')  # this will make a sheet named Users Data
        # Sheet header, first row
        row_num = 0
        font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
        font_style.font.bold = True
        columns = ['id', 'AID', 'Shift_timing', 'EmailID', 'Vendor_Company', 'Project_name',
                   'SerialNumber',
                   'Reason', 'last_updated_time']
        for col_num in range(len(columns)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)  # at 0 row 0 column
        # Sheet body, remaining rows
        font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
        cta_list = CTA.objects.all()
        cta_filter = CTAFilter(request.GET, queryset=cta_list)
        allcta = cta_filter.qs
        rows = allcta.values_list('id', 'AID', 'Shift_timing', 'EmailID', 'Vendor_Company',
                                  'Project_name', 'SerialNumber', 'Reason', 'last_updated_time')

        for row in rows:
            row_num += 1
            for col_num in range(len(row)):
                ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
        wb.save(response)
        return response
```

Comment: Hey @Shailesh - Your update is still not enough. You are not explaining what are the decisions to update or not to update based on. You have 500 records from .xls file and want to allow changing only 200 of them? How do you know, looking at a record, that it came from .xls? It feels like you have some knowledge in your head, but you are assuming too many things and not explaining enough.

Comment: Easy answer to your question "Is there any way through which I can set the max record updation limit in the models.py level?" Is no. You are still not explaining the complete business logic. So you already have 500 items in database and someone uploads another 200, they can be updated? is that it? Can you explain the logic of why some items can be updated and some cant? How is this decision made?

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb
I am having a Django model CTA which is already having 500 user objects. I want to update 200 user shift timing from morning to Evening so for this, I am using the .xls file which will do a lookup in the existing DB records and make changes for match id. (suppose in model Id field is 20912 and if the same id will be present in .xls file then it will update change shift records as per the .xls else if id in the .xls file is not already there in the model then it will create a new object.)

Comment: Ans: We don't want to allow more than 50 % users to Change shift timing in one day because of some server load threshold limit.I am using Django import-export library and whenever I am updating records by inserting in .xls with proper format it will check and for existing id (primary key)it will update the difference in data and if id is not exist in db then simply it will create new records.
And suppose if tomm user want to change data he will download data(filtered based)and in that sheet after changing shift timing he will upload it.

Comment: Thank you. now this is clear explanation and has nothing to do with what you initially said. If I understood you correctly. To do selective update/insert I would do this : 1) select all the objects from the database, that already exist and then update them. 2) Then bulk insert the objects that are new: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

But the bit about 50% of users - this just does not make sense. Imagine using product that only works 50% of time - would you use it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

django-limits does not do what you need. Probably. what django limits does, it applies additional validation to model entry. For example, if your limit is that you can only have 20 active users, that that is exactly what filterset `Q(is_active=True)` checks for.

About your issue of updating models and creating new objects. There are projects and possibilities to update multiple rows with `queryset.update(field=value)` but this updates same column to same value for all the objects in queryset. You probably do not want this. If you want to update 200 objects from database, and you already have some way of getting them from database, when I would do it with single sql query and skip using django ORM : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

about the bulk insert - there are tools for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Now about choosing between which users get to update their data and which ones don't - Do not do this. nobody wants an app that only works 50% of time. If you successfully construct those two queries I mentioned above, then you only hit database three times per .xls upload:

1. to get from database, which object exist
2. pure sql update query
3. Bulk insert of new objects.

This should not trigger load that server cannot handle.

Also the way you use reverse url (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) seems to be faulty:

1. The reverse call does not include object ID and
2. Does not use the view name

Comment: Thank you for replying!. I have updated my question.I want to update records based on primary key which I am uploading through .xls file so for match primary key only changes will be happen but need something which count no of object change and once limit reached it should show ERROR and next day that count should REST itself to 0.